# Swift 3 - localPlayer auth effects SKSpriteNode's action

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, gamekit

Local player auth initial banner effect my sprite node action, stuck 1-2 seconds. And then continue. What should I do for auth local player smoothly?

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

        let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()

        localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {
            (view, error) in

            if view != nil {

                    self.present(view!, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
            else {

                print("call save")
                // self.saveHighscore(5)
                print(GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().isAuthenticated)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code about the node and its action? Also, you shouldn't need to do the authentication on a new thread - Game Kit will do this asynchronously for you once you've set the authentication handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preference is to authenticate as early as possible in the app, as soon as the app starts, well before gameplay starts. Let it happen as soon as the app loads, and be out of the way before you load a scene or start moving nodes.